# Error showing Values of fields msds-memberOfTransitive and msds-memberTransitive

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are trying to return all user information from a LDAP query made to a Microsoft Active Directory 2012 server.

First, we get all attributes from the schema (including msds-memberOfTransitive and msds-memberTransitive), then we make a query requesting all attributes.

We have narrowed down this problem to executing a LDAP search with the following parameters:
 - Scope: Next level (if there are elements inside the container) or Subtree
 - msds-memberOfTransitive or msds-memberTransitive attributes are requested

Sample query reproducing the error:

```
ldapsearch -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=dom" -W -b "CN=Users,DC=my,DC=dom" -h 10.0.1.100 -p 389 msds-memberTransitive
```

Sample query avoiding the error:

```
ldapsearch -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=dom" -W -b "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=dom" -h 10.0.1.100 -p 389 msds-memberTransitive -s one
```

I assume this is some mechanism to avoid excessive calculations of "transitive" attributes, but I have not found anything .

How could I make this search (appart from removing these attributes from the search)?

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: The error is: `result: 1 Operations error\n
text: 00002120: SvcErr: DSID-03120435, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 592062`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [msds-memberOfTransitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn410792.aspx) and [msds-memberTransitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn410792.aspx) have [Search Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223153.aspx) of searchFlags: 2048 set that limit the search to a base Scope.

If we look at [msds-memberOfTransitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn410792.aspx), we see the setting searchFlags: fBASEONLY. Lookin at [Search Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223153.aspx), we see:

(fBASEONLY, 0x00000800): Specifies that the attribute is not to be returned by search operations that are not scoped to a single object. Read operations that would otherwise return an attribute that has this search flag set instead fail with operationsError / **ERROR_DS_NON_BASE_SEARCH**.

(Same is true for [msds-memberTransitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn410792.aspx))
So these attributes will only be return when the scope of the search is BASE.

The only method around this condition would be to loop through each result with one of the attributes and do a second search which would be a baseDN of the entry and a scope of BASE.